# Reading a file from SBT resources folder without escaping characters

Tags: java, scala, io, jvm, sbt

I know we can read from a SBT project resources folder as follows:

```
Source.fromResource("lib.min.js").mkString
```

Now, my file actually contains javascript. If I run the above code, I get a string with escaped characters.

Is there a way to read the file raw? I want to take this raw string and generate a HTML page, so the default behaviour of mkString escaping quotes and < signs screws up the html generation.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the issue? I do not have any escaping before "" and '<' symbols according to your approach.

Comment: Maybe you have an issue inside HTML printing logic?

Comment: Thanks I managed to fix it after reorganizing my code - I think it was HTML issue as you mentioned.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer than (to give me some reputation ^_^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have any escaping before "" and '<' symbols according to your approach. It works.